# Update div dynamically with database values depending on dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

Please see [website](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/guestvibe/index.php).

My database has a table with values 'name' (the event under step 2 on the left), 'price', 'date' etc and I'd like to display them dynamically in the dark box on the right depending on which event is chosen.

I'm currently displaying the event itself with the code below, but I'm unsure as to how to develop it to grab database values based on this choice. I'm guessing some sort of .get().

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>');
    });

    $('#club').change(function(event) {
        $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>');
    });

</script>
```

This has had me stumped for ages, so any help would be much, much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Thanks for your replies. Here's what I now have, but it isn't working.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>');
});

$('#club').change(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "eventinfo.php",
        data:  $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>Price'+data.price);
            },
        dataType: "json"
    });

});

</script>
```

eventinfo.php:

```
    <?php
// the name of the input text box is 'club'
    $night = $_POST['club'];
    $night = mysql_real_escape_string($night);

// one of the columns values included in * is 'price'
// this line was previously: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nights WHERE name = '$night'");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM nights WHERE name = '$night'";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $items = array();

        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                $items[] = array($row[0]);
                }         
        } 

        mysql_close(); 
        // convert into JSON format and print
        echo json_encode($items);
    ?>
```

Comment: You're right. Use `$.ajax` to get the values and then populate.

Comment: And there is a row in your database called price?

Comment: Also it may help to use Firebug for Firefox to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: Looking at Firebug you are returning an empty array so that is why you can't get the price.

Comment: There is definitely a database row called price. Could it be my PHP that isn't creating the array properly? I'm quite weak with PHP arrays...

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action would be to use an xmlhttp object to load your PHP page that echos the data out. From that xmlhttp object you can assign the responseText (which will be the output contents of your PHP page) to a Javascript variable.

In other words, you probably want to use [AJAX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro1/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want an AJAX call to get the price.  So something like

```
$('#club').change(function(event) {
     $.ajax(
     {type: "post",
     url: "/path/to/price",
     data:  $(this).serialize(),
     success: function(data)
     {
      $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>Price'+data.price);
     },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Then since you are using PHP get the values you want and load them into an array and use json_encode.

#### update

For the PHP try changing

```
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $items[] = array($row[0]);
            }         
    }
```

to

```
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $items[] = array("price"=>$row['price']);
            }         
    }
```

#### update #2

Try adding the following to your PHP file, near the top:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I'm still getting the same result!

Comment: Could it be because the array is in a while loop?

Comment: @Sebastian, my bad, I messed up it should have been ```$row['price']``` not ```$row['row']``` assuming there is a price column in your database.

Comment: It's still returning undefined - is there a way of checking if the array is empty or not?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, just render the page in your browser, not via AJAX, and change the code from ```json_encode``` to ```print_r($items)```

Comment: Also, could it be that $night = $_POST['club'] isn't working given that the form hasn't actually been submitted, or does the post in $.ajax take care of that?

Comment: Yep - it returns empty, but isn't that to be expected given that no $night is given to it?

Comment: @Sebastian Try changing ```$_POST['club']``` to ```$_REQUEST['club']``` then go to the site but add ?cclub=Resurrection+%40+The+Place+%26+Ballare to the end of the URL.  The $night should be valid in your AJAX calls as AJAX is handling the post request.

Comment: I've managed to populate the array - see edit of the PHP for what went wrong. But it's still not moving to the Javascript properly!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12502/discussion-between-sebastian-and-travis-pessetto)

Comment: @Sebastaian You need to move the HTML out of it, so no echos except ```json_encode($items)```.  Firebug says your array is:
<br>json:<br>[{"price":"","day":"Wednesday"}] so price is undefined because it has no value and so data.price will output nothing.  data.day should output Wednesday.

Comment: @Sebastian I updated it, see update #2 above, because it may be the Mime-type PHP is sending.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use client side templating.  Use jQuery.tmpl and make a template for the right side (example below):

```
<script id="infoTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <span>${price}</span>
        <span>${information}</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then, make a method in PHP that takes in something like eventId and passes back a JSON object that looks something like this: {"price":"123.34","information":"some info here"}.
To load up your template, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ... other stuff

    $.template("infoTemplate", $("#infoTemplate").html());
});
```

Then, in your change event handler, do this:

```
$('#club').change(function(event) {
    $.get('/yourNewPHPMethod', $('#club').val(), function(data){
        $('#right_inside').html($.tmpl('infoTemplate', data));
    });
});
```

Sorry, didn't have time to test any of  this but it's the main idea and should help you establish a good pattern for any of  this type of work in the future.
See jQuery.tmpl documentation below:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/